# Batch remove the last 4 characters of file if they don't end in .jpg?

Tags: windows, batch-file, directory, rename

Due to a bug in After Effects I'm getting single frame outputs with 4 numbers on the end named like this:

```
Test.jpg0001
Another.jpg0345
AndAnother.jpg0033
```

Is there a batch script I could write to run in a windows folder to remove the last 4 characters if the file doesn't end in .jpg?. So I could continue running the script when I add new files but it will not affect the file that have already been corrected.

Comment: Is it fixed that the numbers being appended would always be 4 digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My goodness, there is no need for any kind of script. A simple rename command is all you need.

This will set the extension to `.jpg` for any file name that contains `.jpg`.

```
ren *.jpg* *.jpg
```

The above is not perfect in that it will improperly rename something like `test.jpg.txt` to `test.jpg.jpg`. It also will rename files like `test2.jpgXYZ` (something other than digits following `.jpg`) to `test2.jpg`. I suspect these limitations will not be a problem.

If you want to be more selective and only rename files that have an extension starting with `.jpg` (ignoring files with `.jpg` in the name followed by some other extension), then you can use FINDSTR regular expressions to filter the files:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b *.jpg*^|findstr /re "\.jpg[^.][^.]*"') do ren "%F" *.jpg
```

If you want to be even more selective and only rename files that end with `.jpg` followed by 1 or more digits, then:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b *.jpg*^|findstr /re "\.jpg[0-9][0-9]*"') do ren "%F" *.jpg
```

If you use either FOR /F statement in a batch file, then you need to double the percents, (`%%F` instead of `%F`).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a VB Script that will search for all extensions starting with JPG and if longer than 3 characters, will rename the files to end with jpg only.  Create a test directory like I did with just a few files and try it out.  It has a hard-coded directory in the code which you'll have to change before you run it (unless your directory is called c:\testdat).  Note to end the folder name with a slash (lazy programming):

```
   set fs = createobject("Scripting.Filesystemobject")

   dirWithFiles = "C:\TestDat\"   ' End with a slash

   set folder = fs.getfolder(dirWithFiles)

   set filescollection = folder.files
   for each file in filescollection
      oldname = dirWithFiles & file.name
      basename = fs.getbasename(file.name)
      extension = fs.getExtensionName(file.name)


      if ucase(mid(extension,1,3)) = "JPG" then
         if len(extension) > 3 then
            newname = dirWithFiles & basename & ".jpg"

            'msgbox "Rename " & oldname  & " to " & newname
            fs.movefile oldname,newname
         end if
      end if
   next
```

Copy this into a file ending with .vbs (I called mine jpgrename.vbs), modify the c:\testdat\ directory name and just put it on your desktop.  Double-click it (under Windows) and it should run.  Here are before and after images:

[image]